# Karma throwing 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined', despite being in my index.html and karma.conf.js file

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, flot

I have been tasked with setting up unit tests for a legacy AngularJS application (none currently exist, so I am setting it all up). However, I have been running into some issues getting my initial test to run. I've been peeling the onion of errors for a while now, but I'm stuck on this current one.

When I run the command 'karma start', it throws the following error (**It must be noted that I am only getting this error while trying to run my unit test, it does not occur when I build the application to run locally**):

```
"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined at Web/js/plugins/flot/curvedLines.js:308:12
```

And that line is the following code: `$.plot.plugins.push(`

I've read multiple github and stackoverflow links, and I've followed their advice, but I am still running into the issue. I have tried putting the script tags near the top of my index.html file, and my karma.conf.js file is definitely including the files for the flot plugin through the line:

```
'Web/js/plugins/**/*.js',
//the full path for the plugin is 'Web\js\plugins\flot'
```

However, I did notice that there is a 'jquery.flot.js' file. **Will the line in my karma conf above include that jquery file?** As an experiment, I also included the following line in my karma.conf.js file:

```
'Web/js/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js'
```

However, when doing so, Karma throws *another* error. This time, saying that I am not loading my main app module, with the exact error being:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

However, I am loading my application at the very top of my unit test file in a before each statement, so I don't know why this would be throwing an error. Additionally, my app is not just called 'app', it has a different name, and I have that differently named module included properly.

So right now, I am a bit lost. **Am I on the right track with including that jquery.flot.js file explicitly in my karma.conf.js file? Or is that the wrong approach and I should only have the** `'Web/js/plugins/**/*.js'` **line? If so, where should I look next?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help anyone, but I figured out my issue.

Apparently, there were some dead plugins that Karma was picking up thanks to my over-reaching statement in the files section. These plugins had dependencies on other packages not included in the project, which threw errors. Excluding these files in karma.conf.js fixed my problem.